Derivation of the upper bound of the average regret of online-to-batch conversion in H-smoothness
I've been studying a paper (Smoothness, Low-Noise and Fast Rates) on the impact of smoothness on the convergence rate of online-to-batch conversion, specifically Theorem 2, which provides a bound on the average regret in the context of online convex optimization. The paper claims that this theorem can be proved using Lemma 3.1 in the original paper and Theorem 1 from this thesis (Online Learning: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications). However, I'm struggling to see the connection between these results. Could someone help clarify how Lemma 3.1 and Theorem 1 from the thesis are used to prove Theorem 2 in the paper?
Lemma 3.1: For an $H$-smooth non-negative function $f : W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, for all $w \in W$:
$$
\|\nabla f(w)\|^* \leq \sqrt{4H f(w)}
$$
Theorem 1: Under the same conditions as Lemma 1. Assume that a constant $L$ exists such that for all $t$, the function $f_t$ is $L$-self-bounded for the norm $\|\cdot\|$. Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be two positive scalars and set $c = L + \sqrt{L^2 + \frac{LU_2}{U_1}}$. Then, for any $u \in S$ that satisfies $f(u) \leq U_1$ and $\sum_{t=1}^{T} g_t(u) \leq U_2$, we have,
$$
R(u, T) = \sum_{t=1}^{T} g_t(w_t) - \sum_{t=1}^{T} g_t(u) \leq 2\sqrt{LU_1U_2} + 4LU_1.
$$
Theorem 2: For any $B \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{L^*}$, if we use stepsize
$$
\eta = \frac{1}{H B^2 + \sqrt{H^2 B^4 + H B^2 n \overline{L^*}}}
$$
for the Mirror Descent algorithm, then for any instance sequence
$z_1, \ldots, z_n \in \mathcal{Z}$, the average regret w.r.t. any
$w^* \in W$ such that $F(w^*) \leq B^2$ and $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \ell(w^*, z_j) \leq \overline{L^*}$
is bounded by:
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ell(w_i, z_i) - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ell(w^*, z_i) \leq \frac{4H B^2}{n} + \frac{2 \sqrt{H B^2 \overline{L^*}}}{n}
$$
I found the proof of Theorem 1 a bit confusing as well, particularly because it doesn't clearly explain the relationship between $U_1, U_2$, and $c$ in that specific manner.
